# What is the purpose of #pragma aux and how should I use it?

Tags: c++, pragma

I'm attempting to delayload a library and use GetProcAddress to get a function from the library to use repeatedly. The project I'm working on has examples of how this being done in other cases, and in the header file that describes typedefs of the function, there is a #pragma aux line. What does this do? Is this always necessary?

EDIT: I'm using the vc11 compiler

Comment: What development system is this?  What compiler?

Comment: That pragma argument is not supported by VC++. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa273917(v=VS.60).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are auxiliary pragmas and it is specific feature for Watcom compiler. From below detailed explanation:

http://users.pja.edu.pl/~jms/qnx/help/watcom/compiler-tools/pragma32.html#AuxiliaryPragmas

> Auxiliary pragmas are used to describe attributes that affect code generation. Initially, the compiler defines a default set of attributes.

so to convert it to Visual Studio, you would have to find equivalent pragmas/compiler features in VS.

Answer (score 2):

`#pragma` implementations are specific for your actual toolchain.

Looking up [`#pragma aux`](https://www.google.de/search?q=c%2B%2B+%22%23pragma+aux%22&rlz=1Y3KTZR_deDE555DE555&oq=c%2B%2B+%22%23pragma+aux%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.18647j0j4&sourceid=chrome-mobile&espv=1&ie=UTF-8) indicates that seems to be a specific *Watcom C/C++ Compiler* specific problem.